# how can I use ActiveRecord Create for multiple records Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby method that returns multiple records with 7 columns. I want to insert these records to the other table which has more than 15 columns.

How can I use the ActiveRecord Create method in my model to insert those records to match exactly into the new table which has the same column name.

### Ex:

I have a model method like the following:

```
def self.record_letter_group
  .....
end
```

In the console, when i try to run this method, it returns the following records

```
([#<Letter::Group User_ID: "sri", Code: "12345", Group_ID: 15>, 
  #<Letter::Group User_ID: "sri", Code: "12445", Group_ID: 15>,
  #<Letter::Group User_ID: "sri", Code: "12545", Group_ID: 15>,
  #<Letter::Group User_ID: "sri", Code: "12645", Group_ID: 15>,
  #<Letter::Group User_ID: "sri", Code: "12745", Group_ID: 15>,
])
```

I want to do something like,

```
save_records = Letter::Category.create(record_letter_group)
```

Note: This `Letter::Category` has `15 columns`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
# whitelist the attributes you want to save to "categories" table
valid_attributes = [ :User_ID, :Code, :Group_ID ]


record_letter_group_attributes = record_letter_group.map { |group| group.attributes.slice(*valid_attributes) }

save_records = Letter::Category.create(record_letter_group_attributes)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the  `*valid_attributes` please?

Comment: And, `group.attributes` return the set of values. But `group.attributes.slice(*valid_attributes)` returns `{}`

Comment: yep, the `valid_attributes` is supposed to be a white list of column names (attributes). For example, if `Letter::Group` has [ :id, :name, :description ] attributes but you only want [ :name, :description ] to be saved to `Letter::Category`, slice(:name, :description) would extract only :name and :description attributes (and remove an :id attribute)

Comment: meaning, you should populate the valid_attributes array with attributes you want, because you might want to skip some (like :id, :updated_at, :created_at) etc

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any other columns. Because I am using joins to select this columns. So I want to insert the selected columns to `Letter::Category`(Letter::Category has 15 columns. I need to select the exact column names and insert the values.

Comment: currently it returns `{}`